# view not displaying anything

Tags: views

I had a view which has been working perfectly fine until today. All of a sudden it doesn't display anything. I took the query which displays at the bottom of the screen and put it into phpadmin and it came up as normal. What is the issue here?

EDIT:
I might have found the issue, but I am very confused. The only thing I have done recently was that I created a template file in my custom theme directory to override the node.tpl.php file (which worked fine). When I changed back to a different theme the view did display properly. I just tried deleting that new template file and clearing the cache, though, but it didn't fix the view.

Comment: What changed on your site?  Restore from yesterday's backup and see if the problem persists.

Comment: if permissions have changed, the sql rewrites drupal does might be causing this.  if you go into advanced settings, you can turn this off and see if it works again, and if so, investigate those permissions.

Comment: @PatrickKenny, how to do you restore yesterdays backup?

Comment: and no, I have not changed any permissions on the site

Comment: @user1015214: I assumed you already had configured daily backups through one of the many available methods.  If you are on shared hosting, your web host may automatically make daily backups for you.  If you are running your own server and not making daily backups, I urge you to learn how to do so and then to start doing so as quickly as possible.

Comment: Perhaps an empty tpl.php which renders blank contents?

Comment: I am running my own site, and no, I have not configured daily backups. Does drupal have something built in for doing this?